# How to format AspectJ *.aj files with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aspectj, ajdt

Am I missing something or is it currently not possible to format AspectJ (*.aj) with eclipse built-in formatter?

I'm using eclipse kepler with AJDT-plugin and the formater doesn't do anything with those files. Currently I'm formatting manually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the formatter. There are certain constructs that are not handled well or are just ignored. I can't quite recall, but I believe declare statements are ignored.  So, it may be that your file does not contain any formattable code.

Also, check your error log to make sure there are no exceptions being thrown.

Comment: You're right. I didn't realized, that a method ITD can be formatted. But "declare @field" statements for example are not formatted by now.